# Ramda: Tutorial incorrect? Order of arguments in R.divide

Tags: ramda.js

I'm new to functional coding, and I've stumbled across following tutorial example:

```
const mathPipe = R.pipe(   // 10
  R.multiply(4),           // 4 * 10
  R.add(2),                // 2 + 40
  R.divide(2)              // 2 / 42
);

mathPipe(10)

> 21
```

When I run this, it gives me `0.047619047619047616` which seems correct to me, since Ramda is function-first, data-second. I added the comments to show what in fact is calculated.

The tutorial however says the expected answer is `21`, so the actual last operation would be `42 / 2`.

So I guess my questions is: Was there a time when the argument order was inverted? Or is the tutorial just plainly incorrect? It is from July 2018.

I hope it's ok to ask this but I'm very new to functional coding and this was just a bit too confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure where your expectations come from.  The function/data ordering is irrelevant.  When you say `R.divide(2)` that means "divide the current value by 2", just as `R.add(4)` means "add 4 to the current value".  Any other interpretation would be unexpected.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is incorrect. Since all Ramda functions are curried, `R.divide(2, 42)` is equivalent to `R.divide(2)(42)` and `R.divide()(2, 42)`. `R.pipe` would pass `42` to `R.divide(2)`, resulting in `2/42` as the result; it does not "divide the current value by 2". To divide current value by 2, you would have to do `R.flip(R.divide)(2)` to make a hole for the first argument.

Comment: I assume you are talking about https://itnext.io/a-beginners-guide-to-ramda-part-1-7e4a34972e97 ? The example is just wrong — the author knows what should happen, as he describes: "Ramdas’ math functions `add`, `multiply`, and `divide` all take 2 parameters, but we are only passing the first parameter in, and the second value will get passed in through the pipe." Thus, he would have known it is `R.divide(2)(current)` (i.e. `2/current`) being evaluated; i.e. Ramda works now exactly as the author explains it — but the code goes against the explanation.

Comment: @Amadan thank you, yes that's the article. I was hoping for the answer you gave, that means I've understood everything so far. You can turn your comment into answer, I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [this article](https://itnext.io/a-beginners-guide-to-ramda-part-1-7e4a34972e97)? The example is just wrong — the author knows what should happen, as he describes:

> "Ramdas’ math functions add, multiply, and divide all take 2 parameters, but we are only passing the first parameter in, and the second value will get passed in through the pipe.

Thus, he would have known it is `R.divide(2)(current)` (i.e. `2/current`) being evaluated; i.e. Ramda works exactly as the author explains it, both now and then. However the result shown in his example contradicts both his explanation, and the actual result.